# How can I use Numpy to obtain a function that represents the relationship between a pair of values and another?

Tags: python, numpy

I am not a mathematician but I *think* that what I am after is called a "multiple linear regression"; please correct me if I am wrong.

I use `numpy.polyfit` and `numpy.poly1d` on a series of angle/pulse_width values from a servo motor, to obtain a function, `angles_to_pulsewidths`.

`angles_to_pulsewidths` is a polynomial function that models the servo and represents a line of good fit for the series. Given an `angle` value, it returns a corresponding `pulse_width`.

I am now trying to do a similar thing but instead of a single `angle` value in my series, I have pair of x/y co-ordinates for each `pulse_width`. I want to obtain a function that given an x/y pair, returns a corresponding `pulse_width`.

This is my code for creating my `angles_to_pulsewidths` function:

```
import numpy

angles_and_pulsewidths = [
    [-162, 2490],
    [-144, 2270],
    [-126, 2070],
    [-108, 1880]
]

angles_values_array =      numpy.array(angles_and_pulsewidths)[:, 0]
pulsewidths_values_array = numpy.array(angles_and_pulsewidths)[:, 1]

coefficients = numpy.polyfit(
        angles_values_array,
        pulsewidths_values_array,
        3
    )

angles_to_pulsewidths = numpy.poly1d(coefficients)
```

I have been trying to modify this so that instead of providing a one-dimensional array of angles I will provide a two-dimensional array of x/y values:

```
xy_values = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
pulse_widths = [2490, 2270, 2070, 1880]
```

However in this case, I can't use `polyfit`, because [that takes only a one-dimensional array for its x parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html).

I can use [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy-linalg-lstsq) instead, but I can't work out what to do with the results it gives me.

I'm also not even sure if I am on the right track; am I? I have read numerous related questions here, and have found numerous clues, but not enough to get me to the next step.

Comment: I would recommend checking out [Scikit Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares). Numpy is great for handling numerical data, but it doesn't go quite that far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use [scipy's `curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for this.

If you know the general format of the function, perhaps you think it will be something of the form:

```
a x ^ 2 + b x y + c y ^ 2 + d x + e y +f
```

then you can use scipy's `curve_fit` to estimate what I will refer to as "parameters": `a, b, c, d, e, f`.

First we need to define the general form of our function:

```
def func(variables, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    x, y = variables
    return a * x ** 2 + b * x * y + c * y ** 2 + d * x + e * y + f
```

Note that our function has 6 parameters, to be able to demonstrate how this works we need more data than parameters so I'm extending your example data set to have 7 pairs of xy values and 7 pulse widths:

```
xy_values = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13]]
pulse_widths = [2490, 2270, 2070, 1880, 2000, 500, 600]
```

(If you do not have more data than parameters then you probably can choose a general form of your function to have less parameters.)

We need to reshape our `xy_values` so that it is not pairs of values but a single pair of two sets of values (the xs and the ys). To do this I'm choosing to creating a numpy array and "transpose" it:

```
xy_values = np.array(xy_values).T
```

We can now call our `func` on our array:

```
func(variables=xy_values, a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=4)
```

Which gives:

```
array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

We can now actually use our data and `curve_fit` to estimate the best parameters:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f=func, xdata=xy_values, ydata=pulse_widths)
```

`pcov` contains information about how good the fit is and popt is the actual values of the parameters which we can directly see and use:

```
popt
```

gives:

```
array([ -25.61043682, -106.84636863,  119.10145249, -374.6200899 ,
        230.65326227, 2141.55126789])
```

and we can call the function with it on some new value of x and y:

```
func([0, 5], *popt)
```

which gives:

```
6272.353891536915
```

Choosing the correct general form of the function you want to fit is case dependant. If there is any knowledge of the problem at hand (perhaps you expect there to be some trigonometric relationship) then you can use it otherwise it's a case of trial and error and getting a relationship that's "good enough" for your use case.

EDIT: Your original suggestion of needing to use multiple linear regression (MLR) is not completely incorrect. The solution approach I've described allows you to do MLR but it just assumes a specific type of `func`: one where all the terms are linear.